# SymPy: Derivatives of KroneckerDelta and indices

Tags: sympy, indexed

Please refer to the following MWE:

```
import sympy as s
x = s.IndexedBase('x')
y = s.IndexedBase('y')
i,j,k = map(s.Idx,['i','j','k'])
a = s.exp(x[i]*y[j]*s.KroneckerDelta(i,j))
b = a.diff(x[j])
```

The value of `b` is [LaTeX rendering of b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enSvt.png). Since I am not allowed to embed images yet, here is the text form

```
((Derivative(KroneckerDelta(i, j), i)*Derivative(i, x[j]) + Derivative(KroneckerDelta(i, j), j)*Derivative(j, x[j]))*x[i]*y[j] + KroneckerDelta(i, j)*y[j])*exp(KroneckerDelta(i, j)*x[i]*y[j])
```

The key point is that there are unevaluated derivatives of `KroneckerDelta` with respect to indices `i` and `j` and derivatives of indices `i` and `j` with respect to `x[i]`. Why are these not `0`?

Comment: Apparently it's a problem in using _Idx_. If you just use ordinary symbols for the indices, the result is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the kind of behaviour I was expecting with symbolic differentiation of indexed variables has not been fully implemented in Sympy yet. I moved on to using other tools like Maxima or Mathematica (or even pen and paper) for these calculations.